# Do Azure Dev Ops Pipelines logging commands support multiline messages?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash and I see you can add messages (that if integrated with GitHub can be posted as PR annotations) using the `##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong.` format.

I don't see anything about multiline messages. Does Azure Dev Ops support that? How can I add a multiline annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `%0D%0A` in your message to wrap lines of your log. For a long single line message, it looks like something as below: 
[image]

After add `%0D%0A`,

```
##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong.Add Workspace. %0D%0AIf Workspace Manager is empty, probably you didn't added one yet.%0D%0AClick on Add button ....
```

It change to  below format：

[image]

For some other kind of error/warning message, you could also take a look at this useful blog-- [Improving Logs in Azure DevOps Service with special ‘tags’](http://hauge.cloud/2018/06/22/improving-logs-in-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-with-special-tags/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the `%0D%0A` trick. What I'm looking for is for this to also appear as multiline when the annotation is posted to GitHub. Initially I was thinking in replacing `\n` with `\\n`. I'll try as soon as I can and see if it works.

Comment: Patrick, this is a related issue https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Issues.Recipe/issues/134. Is there any way to keep the color of the lines the same color as the first line (in your case it is purple)? Or is this a lacking feature not working yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here the command that worked fine for me, it will replace '\n' line returns characters in your text :

Sed command will replace all '\n' with %0D%0A and add a final '\n' at the end of the text.

```
sed -z 's/\n/%0D%0A/g;s/,$/\n/'
```